# Ajax request under WP - script simple doesn't work at all

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I started learnig about AJAX request under WP but unfortunatelly i stuck on the very beginings and don't know what i doing wrong. I wrote very basic code with doesn't work at all. I read documentation but it won't help so i decided to ask you where is the problem.

PHP

```
function pt_get_participants(){
    echo json_encode('test');
}

protected function filtrateParticipants($update = false, $dataToFiltration=[]){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pt-script-main', get_parent_theme_file_uri().'/assets/js/ptAjaxHandler.js' , array(), '1.0.0', true );
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    wp_localize_script( 'pt-script-main', 'pt_data', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php', $protocol),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( "pt_participant_nonce" ))
    );
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pt_get_participants', array($this, 'pt_get_participants'));
    add_action('wp_ajax_pt_get_participants',array($this, 'pt_get_participants'));
}
```

Java Script

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data = {
            action: 'pt_get_participants',
            nonce: pt_data.pt_participant_nonce,
            success: 'success'
        };
        $.get(pt_data.ajax_url, data, function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
    });
    console.log('test');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: where, in the PHP code, do you call any of the functions you have shown? Are you expecting / hoping that `action: 'pt_get_participants'` will invoke the PHP function `pt_get_participants`??

Comment: yes, i expect that wp_ajax do that for me. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data = {
            action: pt_get_participants.ajax_url,
            nonce: pt_data.pt_participant_nonce,
            success: 'success'
        };
        $.get(pt_data.ajax_url, data, function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
    });
    console.log('test');
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you invoke filtrateParticipants method and where?

Doing something like this in your class constructor might help

```
add_action('init', [ $this, 'filtrateParticipants'] );
```

Also, you have a typo in your code

You are pasing parameter called **nonce**

'**nonce**' => wp_create_nonce( "pt_participant_nonce" ))

And you are trying to use it as **pt_participant_nonce**

nonce: pt_data.**pt_participant_nonce**